# List attachment count per user in Exchange online (O365)

Tags: microsoft-office-365, attachment

Is there any way to list attachment usage in outgoing emails of all users?

I would like to run a campaign at our company to make users aware of better options than using an attachment, and having the data to support the campaign (and to measure its success) would be grand!
For starters, just having a simple "count" of the number of attachments sent by each individual would make a huge impact, I believe (but I look forward to refining this later on).

Comment: `I would like to run a campaign at our company to make users aware of better options than using an attachment` - What's wrong with attachments? What better options are there? Is this "campaign" something being mandated by the company or your boss, or is this just your opinion and you're trying to impose your will on the end users? I'm asking because I'm curious about what's driving this "campaign".

Comment: Sharing links to files on OneDrive, SharePoint or similar are often way better options (we see a lot of people still working with "please provide comments on this document" by sending a copy of the document around which is terribly inefficient.

Comment: Not for nothing, but this sounds like you're doing this based on your opinion on what's "better" or "more efficient" and not necessarily based on the needs of the business nor as a mandate from the business. How does the number of attachments sent support your argument? How does the number of attachments prove that using OneDrive or Sharepoint are better? Better in what sense? Have you quantified and qualified your argument? What's the "problem" that you're trying to solve, other than imposing your own opinion on the end users?

Comment: I'm not trying to give you a hard time. These are the same questions I ask myself and my colleagues. "Are we doing this for the client or for ourselves?" "Is this what the client wants or is it what we want?"

Comment: It will not prove that working through a shared file instead of copies works better (this we already know; we've seen too many people sending copies of files and then manually copy the edits in all of the copies to one central copy: this is very time consuming and adds no value). We would use this count as an awareness raiser within the organization (monthly mail with the "sent count" compared to company/division average, plus instructions on "better ways". So, yes: we are doing this for our users (it doesn't actually make any difference for us - neither bandwidth nor storage are an issue).